# Pytorch how use a linear activation function

Tags: keras, pytorch

In Keras, I can create any network layer with a linear activation function as follows (for example, a fully-connected layer is taken):

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(outs, input_shape=(160,), activation='linear'))
```

But I can't find the linear activation function in the PyTorch documentation. ReLU is not suitable, because there are negative values in my sample. How do I create a layer with a linear activation function in PyTorch?

Comment: A purely linear function on hidden layers is absolutely useless. Also, ReLU wont be 0 if you have x<0: weights can be negative.

Comment: maybe he is asking it for the last layer...for a regression problem. torch.nn.Linear(160, outs) works fine. No 'linear' activation needs to be explicitly specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the Keras documentation, you will see [`tf.keras.layers.Dense`](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/)'s `activation='linear'` corresponds to the `a(x) = x` function. Which means no non-linearity.

So in PyTorch, you just define the linear function without adding any activation layer:

```
torch.nn.Linear(160, outs)
```

Comment: Well, is it possible to make a linear activation function not for a fully connected layer, but for a convolutional one? If I don't specify an activation function for some layer (whether convolutional or fully connected), then my network is not trained at all. I am using a LeNet-5 adaptation for a 1-channel 30*30 images.

Comment: "*is it possible to make a linear activation function not for a fully connected layer, but for a convolutional one?*" did you read both answers? `activation='linear'` means no activation. I am not sure where you're getting at with a linear activation on a conv layer.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure that in this case, when the backpropagation error, the derivative will be passed. And I'm talking about the use of linear activation in PyTorch.

Comment: Let's start again: you want to implement a dense layer with `activation='linear'` in PyTorch. `Dense` layer is a fully connected layer i.e., `nn.Linear`, and `activation='linear'` means ***no*** activation (i.e., no non-linearity function). Where's the issue? Maybe I didn't make that clear `torch.nn.Linear` is equivalent to `tf.keras.layers.Dense` with `activation='linear'` on.

Comment: I showed an example of how to apply the linear activation function in Keras. Now I'm interested in how it can be used in PyTorch. I.e., as far as I understand, torch.nn. linear creates a fully connected layer with the default linear activation function. The question is: if this is the case, how do I add a linear activation function already for the convolutional layer in PyTorch?

Comment: You don't understand, let me try to explain. In Keras the fully connected layer is `tf.keras.layers.Dense`, and it comes with the `activation` parameter which you can use to append a non-linear function (*a.k.a.* an **activation** function) to it. For example: `Dense` with `activation='relu'` is equivalent to `nn.Linear()` + `nn.ReLU()`. The default is `activation='linear'` which means ***no*** activation is appended, equivalent to `nn.Linear()`. If you want `activation='linear'` that means you want ***no*** activation. So use your PyTorch layer as is: `nn.Conv2d`.

Answer (score 1):

`activation='linear'` is equivavlent to no activation at all.

As can be seen [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/linear), it is also called "passthrough", meaning the it does nothing.

So in *pytorch* you can simply not apply any activation at all, to be in parity.

However, as already told by @Minsky, hidden layer without **real** activation, i.e. some **non-linear activation** is useless. It is like changing the weights which is anyway done during the network taining.

Comment: Well, is it possible to make a linear activation function not for a fully connected layer, but for a convolutional one? If I don't specify an activation function for some layer (whether convolutional or fully connected), then my network is not trained at all. I am using a LeNet-5 adaptation for a 1-channel 30*30 images.

Comment: You're not doing enough research. @senek

Answer (score 1):

As already answered you don't need a linear activation layer in pytorch. But if you need to include it, you can write a custom one, that passes the output as follows.

```
class linear(torch.nn.Module):
    # a linear activation function based on y=x
    def forward(self, output):return output
```

The you can call it like any other activation function.

```
linear()(torch.tensor([1,2,3])) == nn.ReLU()(torch.tensor([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume correct you are doing this due to trying to plug it into some module you built where it takes an 'activation' as argument but now you don't want any.
You can just use a linear layer like:

```
nn.Linear(1,1)
```

which actually added a parameter which is not the same as passthrough above but works too.